# Best way to serialize Model in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, serialization

If I have Model and I want to serialize it to JSON to use in code, how can I do it better? I must use Reader/Writer or there is some other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ext.encode` for this specifically. (returns `string` of the `json`)

`var json = Ext.encode(this.getStore().data.items[0].data);`

More info available on [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-encode)